# Facebook Graph API cURL Request with campaign status

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, guzzle

I am trying to figure out how to query my Facebook Campaigns to filter out Active, Deleted, etc...

I use this, and it loads ALL of my campaigns, and doesn't matter based upon my status selected. I am hoping that it's something basic, but I have tried all variations with not change in my results.

*Obviously I have removed the access_token on purpose.*

**In Short:** How do I get campaigns based upon their status'.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a `filtering` object as specified on this API page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters

Here is an example provided on the API page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/

```
curl -G \
-d "level=ad" \
-d "filtering=[{'field':'ad.effective_status','operator':'IN','value':['ARCHIVED']}]" \
-d "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/insights/"
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah that didn't work. going to try some other stuff here too

Comment: Gave me        "message": "(#100) param filtering must be an array.",

Comment: Updated with an example straight from a different API page.

Comment: Ahhh yeah, that works, thank you. Appreciate your time!